# Prevent save changes dialog box upon closing

Tags: excel, vba

I have spreadsheet which uses events upon opening, therefore anytime I try to close the file, the save changes dialog box appears.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: Post the code what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a function in VBA to ThisWorkbook to let Excel think that the file has been saved. This will prevent any save prompts.

If you don't want to save your workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Me.Saved = True

End Sub
```

If you want to save your workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Me.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Answers the question asked!

Answer (score 1):

Here [documentation](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-worksheet/) for deleting work sheet.

So, you need to use as follow:

```
'Stopping Application Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts=FALSE

'~~~~~~deleting sheet~~~~~

'Enabling Application alerts once we are done with our task
Application.DisplayAlerts=TRUE
```

Comment: Mind that this will prevent ANY dialogues and alerts during the task. I dont know if this is desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```